# Creating a slide-in/-out partially hidden toolbar in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I need some help to find examples or descriptions on how to create a View that slides in/out on the "main activity view".

I have not seen this in any app so far, so I tried to describe it using an image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEEpU.jpg

The main idea is that it should only be partially hidden when closed, so by touching the visible "knob", the toolbar slides out fully visible again.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  If you found my answer  (or any other for that matter) to be the proper one (or most helpful) you should click the check mark next to that answer to accept it.  If it was really helpful an additional upvote is a good indicator of your appreciation of that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closest you'll get is a Sliding Drawer (which is pretty close).

[See here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html)

Doing a bit of reading about it it seems you can have it slide up from the bottom or out from the left edge.  Haven't come across any info that would let you make it drop from the top or come from the right edge...

Comment: SlidingDrawer is deprecated at of API level 17, unfortunately. There is probably still some time to use it, but hopefully there is an easy way to do this reliably without it.